# Is $\mathbb{R}$ a covering of $S^1 \vee S^1$?

Tags: general-topology

If so, doesn't this make it a universal covering? Hatcher gives $S^1 \vee S^1$ the universal cover [image: here] but doesn't the map $x \in (0,4\pi) \to \begin{cases} (\cos(x),\sin(x)) & 0<x\leq 2\pi\\ (2-\cos(x), \sin(x)) & 2\pi \leq x < 4\pi \end{cases}$ define a 1-fold covering and by extension $\mathbb{R}$ is a countable covering of $S^1\vee S^1$?

Comment: A $1$-fold covering is also known as a homeomorphism, but no it's not; what makes you think it is ?

Comment: That isn't a local homeomorphism.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown: how isn't it? Can you elaborate?

Comment: @PedroBach The issue is at the base point (where the two copies of $\mathbf{S}^1$ have been joined).

Comment: @Max did you see the map I described? This seems to me to map R to the wedge of two circles (immersed in R^2)

Comment: @Hayden what's the issue exactly? The conditions for a covering state that an open neighborhood of every point in the covering (i.e. a neighborhood of 2π) maps to an open neighborhood of $S^1\vee S^1$ which seems to hold in this case. Or must the open neighborhood on $S^1\vee S^1$ at their common point include a "cross"?

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry. My issue is that I was still thinking of the neighborhood as being one-dimensional whereas at the point of tangency of the circles, the neighborhood is two-dimensional.

Comment: @PedroBach It is not two dimensional, it is still one dimensional. It's not about dimension. The point is that every neighbourhood of the glueing point contains X shape which cannot be homeomorphically mapped into any open subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: By definition preimage of a certain open neighbourhood $U$ of the glueing point has to be a disjoint union of open subsets such that they are mapped homeomorphically by $f$ onto $U$. And your $f$ fails to satisfy that.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an answer to your question which compiles together the information in the comments.

There does not exist any covering map $f : \mathbb R \mapsto S^1 \vee S^1$.

For the proof, suppose that $f$ exists. It follows immediately from the definition of a covering map that for each $q \in S^1 \vee S^1$ and each $p \in f^{-1}(q)$ there exist open neighborhoods $V \subset S^1 \vee S^1$ of $q$ and $U \subset \mathbb R$ of $p$ such that $f$ restricts to a **homeomorphism** $f : U \to V$.

Now consider the case that $q$ is the "wedge point" of $S^1 \vee S^1$. Inside the open neighborhood $V$ of $q$ we may find another open neighborhood $V' \subset V \subset S^1 \vee S^1$ of $q$ such that $V'$ is connected and $V'-q$ has 4 connected components. Since $f^{-1} : V \to U$ is a homeomorphism, it follows that $U' = f^{-1}(V')$ is an open neighborhood $U' \subset U \subset \mathbb R$ of $p$ such that $U'$ is connected and $U'-p$ has 4 connected components. But $U'$ is an open interval, and $U'-p$ has only 2 connected components, a contradiction.

---

Now, there is still the issue of the map you propose; what is wrong with that map?

In order for your map $f$ to be a covering map, there must exist an arbitrarily small connected neighborhood $V \subset S^1 \times S^1$ of the wedge point $q$ such that for every connected component $U$ of $f^{-1}(V)$, the restricted map $f : U \to V$ is a homeomorphism. Your map does not satisfy that property. For instance, one may choose $V$ to be connected and so that $V-q$ has 4 connected components. But your domain $(0,4\pi)$ is an open subinterval, and every open connected subset of $(0,4\pi)$ is also an open subinterval and the complement of each point in that subinterval has 2 connected components.